# is not a valid virtual path error

Tags: asp.net

This is my code for downloading text file. But the server.transfer method is not able to resolve that path. It is giving   "is not a valid virtual path error"

```
        string filePath = @"D:/BCPResult/Cust_File.t`enter code here`xt";
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
           "attachment; filename=" + filePath);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        Response.End();
```

Please guide me...

Answer (score 2):

If your file path is not related to server you do not need `Server.MapPath`.

Also if you run your code in windows, path separator is \, not /.

This code must work:

```
string filePath = @"D:\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt";
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filePath);
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use '\' (backslash) instead '/'.

```
string filePath = @"D:\BCPResult\Cust_File.txt";
```

or

```
string filePath = "D:\\BCPResult\\Cust_File.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

If You Are trying to access a file from the Remote URL or External URL like (https://www.example.com/)

then you have to Use for the web client like this

string url=  "this is the URL of the file from where you want to access the file"

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient(); 
        byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData(url); 
        if (mimetype != null)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = mimetype;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        }
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        context.Response.End();
```